# Setting the UITableView of the class "hides" the outlet part of the outlets

Tags: swift, uitableview, storyboard

I've made a child class of `UITableViewController` and then set it the view in the `UIStoryboard`.

The problem is that when starting the app the screen gets black and I think that might be because the View outlet of the view is not correctly set.
I saw that the outlets where different by comparing this view to the others: 
I do not have the "Outlets" part of the outlets and so cannot connect the "view" and table outlets.

Removing the class from the view will let those outlets (in the unconnected state) be displayed.

What is going on?

- **outlets without the class set**:

[image]

- **outlets with the class set**:

[image]

Comment: If you think your question is misunderstanded try to add some code or some pictures about your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have been able to find what was causing this, but I don't know why it does not.

First in the file where my DevicesViewController: UITableViewController class is declared, I had extensions of the class declared **before** the class declaration.

Second in another file I had an extension of DevicesViewController declared.

Taking all the extensions of DevicesViewController an declaring them in the same file, **after** the class solved the problem.

Seems like a bug of Xcode/Swift.
Setting extensions at another place than after the class will cause this problem, which is the same problem than when I set the class of the view to a non existing class. I think that Xcode cannot find the class if it founds an extension to this class before finding the class itself.
I conclude that the extensions of a view controller needs to be declared **in the same file** and **after** the class of the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

If your outlets tab disappear from your **connectors inspector** something is happened in the **identity inspector**:

[image]

where you have change the class field of appartenence.

In fact they are directly connected so any change of class type reflects the IBOutlets code belonging to that class and the **connector inspector** will be update with that IBOutlets list present in that class.

As explained in the comment below, you must selected the "yellow button" like this image:

[image]

to specify the class where you want to link, the other voices below the yellow row Preload View Controller in my example are the object inside the class like View etc..

**UPDATE**:
In the link your have reported in your comment (https://github.com/luinily/hOme/blob/VIP-Object-Creator/hOme/Scenes/Devices/DevicesViewController.swift) there aren't IBOutlets so it's correct you never see it in the **connectors inspector**

Comment: Thanks for your answer

I understand that thanks, the thing is that the Class I assign inherits UITableViewController:

class DevicesViewController: UITableViewController {
}

For other TableViewControllers setting a class that inherits UITableViewController do not hide the outlets. I've tried to see what is different between the classes that do not cause problems but I can't see anything.

Here is a link to the class I set to the view
https://github.com/luinily/hOme/blob/VIP-Object-Creator/hOme/Scenes/Devices/DevicesViewController.swift

Comment: Voted your answer up! 
Did not validate it as it is not enough to solve the problem yet.

Comment: You must always assing the custom name of the class, not the generic typology like UIViewController or UITableViewController, they cannot have the IBOutlets you report in your custom class. For example if you are in the Storyboard .Now I will update my answer to indicate how to.

Comment: P.S. I dont want your vote if you dont solve your problem, I want you solve your problem and, after, if you want to vote do it otherwise forget it. I've speaking about it because many people leave question and answers alone without any comments or news about the issue.

Comment: Yes thank you.
I do put the class name in the field in the identity inspector.

Thanks for having taken a look to my class. I understand that I don't have any outlet in the class itself but removing the class from the View would display the outlet "view <-> Table View" and creating a new empty class (so no outlets) inheriting from UITableViewController would also display it.
Why would it be different from my class?

I'm talking about the "outlets" part between Triggered Segues and Presenting Segues

Comment: You cannot declare an interface builder structure different by the code, everything must matched. If you change your view in the UI part by removing is customClass, you broke the link between the object in the code and the object in the design editor. It's like you work in your code with a View different by your XIB

Comment: Yes I understand that.

What I would like to know is why any class inheriting UITableViewController would let me see the "view <-> TableView" outlet, but not my DevicesViewController Class.

As it is also inheriting UITableViewController it should behave the same way but is not. I'd like to understand why.

Comment: Because the view refeer to UITableView , not to UITableViewController. When you look at the GLOBAL class , you look at the controller, in your case to a custom UITableViewController aka DevicesViewController. the view is just a component of the class, and in your case you use the native UITableView , not a custom table. UITableViewController is the class with delegates and methods, UITableView is only the simple table so it is correct you see view <-> UITableView.

Comment: Thank you for everything. I could find a "solution" by myself and wrote an answer :)